# AngularJS tutorial 'checkmark' filter, clearer return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may be more a JavaScript question, but the code is from the AngularJS tutorial. Question is, how can I get this code to work:

My Changes, I want return to be a bit more explicit, but this fails:

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  var isChecked = function(input) {
    return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
  };

  return isChecked(input);
});
```

ORIGINAL from the tutorial:

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
  };
});
```

Here's the tutorial page:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that original code returns a *function* (in `return function(input)` statement). That means you should return a function too:

```
return isChecked; // instead of `return isChecked(input);`
```

... and not the result of calling it. BTW, there's no need to use a variable for this - it's enough (for both commenting and debugging purposes) to name the function within its expression:

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function getCheckmark(input) {
    return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
  };
});
```

*I've changed the function's name, because it returns not a boolean (what you'd probably expect from method named `isXXX`) - but a character, based on whether or not its input is falsy value.*

Comment: Thanks. I also tried "return isChecked()", but now I see the issue, i was returning the return value of the function, not the actual function itself.